# Phalcon PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught exception with message 'Unknown Expression'

Tags: php, phalcon, uncaught-exception

I am attempting to follow the REST application tutorial [provided by Phalcon](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html), but I keep running into problems when I attempt to insert data.  My problem is that I have no idea what this error is supposed to mean.  I believe that it's an error within Phalcon, but my knowledge of C is nonexistent.  Let me know if I should provide more context.

Here's the error that shows up in the PHP error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Exception' with message 'Unknown expression' in /home/acarbonaro/testApplication/index.php:84\n
Stack trace:\n
0 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->_getExpression(274, false)\n
1 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->_prepareInsert()\n
2 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->parse()\n
3 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->execute(Array, NULL)\n
4 /home/acarbonaro/testApplication/index.php(84): Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Manager->executeQuery('INSERT INTO Pro...', Array)\n
5 [internal function]: {closure}()\n
6 /home/acarbonaro/testApplication/index.php(115): Phalcon\\Mvc\\Micro->handle()\n
7 {main}\n
  thrown in /home/acarbonaro/testApplication/index.php on line 84
```

Here's the code for the POST route with line numbers for reference.

```
71: $app->post('/api/products', function() use ($app) {
72:     if ($app->request->isPost() == true) {
73:         if ($app->request->isAjax() == true) {
74:             $product = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();
75:             $partNumber = $product->partNumber;
76:         }
77:         $partNumber = $app->request->getPost('partNumber');
78:     }
79: 
80:     $phql = "INSERT INTO Products (partNumber) VALUES (:partNumber:)";
81:     $params = array(
82:         'partNumber' => $partNumber
83:     );
84:     $status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, $params);
85: 
86:     // Prep the response
87:     if ($status->success() == true) {
88:         $response->setStatusCode(201, "Created");
89: 
90:         $product->id = $status->getModel()->id;
91: 
92:         $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'OK', 'data' => $product));
93:     } else {
94:         $response->setStatusCode(409, "Conflict");
95: 
96:         // Send errors to the client
97:         $errors = array();
98:         foreach($status->getMessages() as $message) {
99:             $errors[] = $message->getMessage();
100:         }
101:  
102:         $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'messages' => $errors));
103:     }
104:  
105:     return $response;
106: });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
80:     $phql = "INSERT INTO Products (partNumber) VALUES (:partNumber)";
81:     $params = array(
82:         ':partNumber' => $partNumber
83:     );
84:     $status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, $params);
```

I have no experience with this Phalcon you speak of, but from the stack trace it appears to be using PDO.

Line 80: Removed the last colon to have ... VALUES (:partNumber)";

Line 82: Added a colon to the start of the array key so you have ':partNumber' =>

That will then be a valid PDO prepare() statement. Your mileage may vary, but that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: I switched to using PDO, but it threw a different error.  I think that PHQL is configured properly with Phalcon, and that it's an issue with Phalcon itself.